# Java Debugging - Concurrency of Exceptions

Tags: java, debugging, exception, netbeans, concurrency

I am using java with netbeans IDE and I am trying to debug to the output window.  My log prints to the output window in run-order except for exceptions, which tend to print ahead of their order in the running of the code.  Here is an example of the output -

19:45:53.266 :            Checking to see if we are past start point
19:45:53.267 :                           Error in SortRequestIdList.  Exception = [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;
19:45:53.266 :            We are past the start point.  Checking to see our position relative to the bounds
19:45:53.266 :            We are below the lower bound.  About to run RunnerBelow
19:45:53.267 :                      Error in ListLex.  Exception = null
19:45:53.266 :                  ***** Entering RunnerBelow *****

So the exceptions are printing 'ahead of time'.  Is there a way I can get control of when these print so that (event A runs before event B) => (debug output for A appears before event B)?

Thanks for any help you guys could offer with this!

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`printStackTrace` uses `System.err`, while for all other output you probably use `System.out`. Either use `System.err.println` in your code (simple solution), or make a method that will accept an exception and print its stacktrace to `System.out` (quite a bit harder).

Answer (score 2):

Exceptions normally are printed using System.err, while normal debug messages will be written to System.out. As two different streams are used to create the output, sometimes you will see exceptions written before any debug messages that occurred before the exception.

If you can change the code that produces the messages, I would suggest adding output to System.out in your catch block. (You could use System.out.println(e.getMessage())). If this is not possible you could print the relevant debug messages to System.err.

Comment: Ah, thanks, makes sense.  I can remove the uses of System.err, but they are useful because they highlight my output in red, whereas everything else is black.. Is there a way to choose the output text color?  Thanks!  -Add: I'm going to have a play around with http://www.diogonunes.com/it/work/jcdp/ )

Comment: JCDP looks promising, never heard of that before. Though I'm not sure if it will work with the NetBeans console. Other than that, the coloring of System.err output is done by your IDE, I don't have experience with NetBeans, so I have no idea if you can change the color of the output, but you might want to look into the properties there.

Comment: PS - For anyone is interested in getting this to work : the JCDP site provides the latest JANSI jar file in the download, but the JANSI developers have altered the methods, making them incompatible with JCDP.  If you want to use JCDP, so to http://jansi.fusesource.org/download.html and download an earlier version of JANSI (I've just tried 1.0 and it works)